# Open load bearing wall

Tags: walls, structural

There's a wall in my house that I'd like to open to widen a room. The beam (a single 6x10 of hard wood) above is sitting on the concrete foundation at each extremity of the house (10in wide concrete) and there's 3 steel columns that supports it. In between the steel columns, there's a wall made of 2x3s every 16 inches (some are doubled in the center).

```
|-----------------------------------|< 10in concrete
|                                   |
|                                   |
========O=========O=========O======== <- support beam (sits on concrete)
|                                   |
|                                   |
|-----------------------------------|< 10in concrete
^                                   ^ 
10in concrete                       10in concrete 

O = position of the steel columns
```

[image: Wall]

**I won't touch the 3 steel columns, they will remain where they are.**

Can I remove those 2x3s?

EDIT:
Photo of the top of the steel

[image]

Top of another column:
[image]

Comment: you should be able to remove the wall ... i would be surprised if the top of the wall is even touching the steel beam

Comment: We can’t see the beam yiu say is supported  by the jack posts. What size is that beam and what kind of  beam is it? Does the wall attach to the beam?

Comment: Yeah sorry the picture is bad, on top of the steel column there’s something that looks like a 2x6 or 2x8 then beam is sitting on it. It was like that when I bought the house. The beam is a single 6x10 of hard wood.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can remove the 2x3 stud wall.

There is 1) single top plate, 2) no plywood for shear wall construction, 3) no hold-downs for uplift or “racking” considerations, 4) the steel posts are close enough together to support 17 train locomotives (well, a significant load).

2x3’s are not used for structural walls.

Is that an adjustable cap on that steel post?

Comment: It’s a 2x6 or 2x8 then beam sits on it. The other 2 don’t have that and the beam sits directly on it. Not sure why this one has this (was like that when I bought).